# Is there a word for 'non-material but physical' but not 'energy propagation'?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for 'non-material but physical'. The term should mean that there is no material representation but possibly a physical or physically measurable effect.

One example would be an acoustic wave, however, the topic in question is not about acoustic waves and I must avoid the word 'energy propagation'.

Comment: In what sense is an acoustic wave physical but non-material? It is, presumably, propagating in some material such as air or a guitar string or some such. I think if you make that clear you will be able to more easily pick the right word.

Comment: Is the difference between electromagnetic "waves" (such as light, which doesn't need a physical "medium" through which to propagate), and acoustic waves (sound, which *does* require a "medium") relevant here?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the word **phenomenon** is used for a physical effect, whether material or non-material. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/phenomenon) has

> **phenomenon**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1** A fact or situation that is observed to exist or happen, especially one whose cause or explanation is in question.
> *glaciers are interesting natural phenomena*

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phenomenon) has

> **phenomenon**
> **1** an observable fact or event